# Finding the size of a files in a directories

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Hello I am passing directories to my shell script and searches for every file in them with size [5;30].Here is the script

```
    for i in $* ; do 
      for j in $(ls $i) ; do
          size=$(wc -c $j | awk '{print $1}')

             if [ $size -ge 5 ] && [ $size -le "30"]
                then 
                      echo $j
                fi
         done
     done
```

However I get the error : line 5[: -ge unary operator exprected.Any ideas why?

Comment: Many, many problems with your script.  [`shellcheck`](https://www.shellcheck.net/) can find some of them.  Aside from those, you should probably use `wc -c <"$file"` instead of `wc -c "$file" | awk '{print $1}'`.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the difference between the two of them

Comment: Err, the former doesn't need `awk`?

Comment: Another way to get the file size is the stat(1) command.

`stat --printf="%s" $file`

Note that the options and format may be different on BSD and OSX systems.

Comment: @Deathgrip `s/may be/are/`.  Which is why for getting the size is preferable to use `wc -c`, which is portable.  It's also efficient: all implementations I'm aware of use `stat()` / `fstat()` when possible, instead of reading the file.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps just use a one line find command.

```
find "$@" -type f -maxdepth 1 \( -size +4c -a -size -31c \)
```

Comment: I believe you may drop the `-a` and the parentheses. There's an implicit _and_ between all tests.

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes you're correct. For me it's a force of habit to use parentheses when I'm doing multiple tests. Helps not forget to use them when mixing 'ands' and 'ors'.

Comment: `-maxdepth` and `-type` are tests too :-)